# How does a person get all but the first and last element of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How do you make a copy of a string with the first and last character removed?

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| `$hello$` | `hello` |

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do it

```python
istring[1:-1]
```

---

#### Demonstration

```python
# `istring` represents `input string`
istring = "$hello$"

# `ostring` represents `output string`
ostring = istring[1:-1]

print(ostring)
# storage location labeled `ostring` now contains `hello` without `$`
```

---

### Table of the Indexed String

| CHARACTER | `$` | `h` | `e` | `l` | `l` | `o` | `$` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REVERSE INDEX | -7 | -6 | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 |
| INDEX | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

---

### Additional Explanation

Note that python always subtracts one from the upper limit of a slice index. Thus...

> - `istring[1:2]` is elements `1` through `1` (inclusive)
> - `istring[1:3]` is elements `1` through `2` (inclusive)
> - `istring[1:4]` is elements `1` through `3` (inclusive)
> - `istring[1:-1]` is elements `1` through `-2` (inclusive)

Comment: Since the answer seems to have been posted seconds after the question, this seems like an attempt to use Stack Overflow as a personal blog. I'm not sure that this is a valid use of the site.

Comment: @JohnColeman It's possible this is a duplicate, but it's not an unreasonable question to post with the intent of a self-answer. (I'm not sure the table is necessary, nor is an extended explanation of indexing and slicing particularly on-topic.)